# Top bar sites selection dropdown differently aligned on Meta stack exchange

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

Somehow, here on Meta stack exchange, the drop down for the site selection is slightly more on the left than on other sites I visit (SO and Arqade mainly).

Nothing like screenshots with hand-drawn circles to show what I mean :

[image: Arqade]
[image: SO]
[image: Meta stack exchange]

Notice the slight difference on the last picture. My bookmarks from Firefox aren't moving.

It might be designed as such but it felt strange when changing tabs from here to SO or Arqade. I can't tell why as on Arqade, I have about as much rep as here, so it doesn't seem the rep size or not having the review link matters.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's intended to be there or not, but the stylesheet for Meta Stack Exchange has an extra rule defined in it that overrides the normal 980px width of the topbar wrapper (which every other site would use) with a 1000px width. The 20px difference would cause the topbar to be 10px longer on each side.

```
.topbar .topbar-wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

```
.topbar .topbar-wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 34px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}
```